# Complexity Classes - separations and inclusions

Tags: complexity-classes

What are the basic complexity class seperation and inclusion results that everybody should know? (I mean specifically results that are known, and the proofs can be understood by a non-expert)

It would be great to have a book or paper (or set of papers) which go through and prove all the simplest and most fundamental results in this area. Where could I find it?

Thank you.

Comment: To those who down-vote, or vote to close: Please see http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/396/873

Comment: I voted to close this as off-topic. The question seems to be too elementary (as we can see from the answers below: one is a very well-known textbook and the other one is a web site [from our faq](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/229#229)).

Comment: Answer can be found by googling.

Comment: @Jukka: You are right, yet I think we can help OP to restate the question. For example, one can ask: What are you exactly after? Do you have anything special in mind? Allowing some time will resolve such issues. As per the link on meta I just posted, please do not down-vote/vote-to-close quickly after a question is posted.

Comment: The Zoo has a specific section called the Petting Zoo, which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Sadeq: Actually it seems that we already waited *too* long before closing this question. You already gave an answer and the answer was accepted.

Comment: @Jukka: I beg to differ. No offence, but if I were muad, I would accept an answer in a rush, before the question gets too attention, resulting in more negative reps. In fact, I have made such a decision when I posted one of my earliest questions :)

Comment: You got a useful answer to your question; hence you shouldn't be discouraged. (Even if this question *was* closed, and even if you hadn't had got useful answers by then, [you shouldn't be discouraged](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/361#361). Closing is cheap, it doesn't cost your reputation, and you have always the opportunity to try to rephrase your question and re-ask it.)

Comment: I lean toward closing only because any decent textbook on complexity theory would answer your question. And Complexity Zoo is the perfect place for checking separations/inclusions and references. As Jukka said, please don't be discouraged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like [Papadimitriou's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201530821).

Specially, it has "Class Review" sections at the end of several chapters, illustrating the relations among complexity classes.

The relevant sections are:

- Section 10.4.1 (page 235): P, NP, coNP.

  Section 11.5.1 (page 272): P, ZPP, RP, coRP, BPP, NP, coNP, PP.

  Section 15.5.1 (page 385): AC, NC, RNC, P.

  Section 16.4.1 (page 405): NC$_1$, L, SL, RL, SC, NL, PolyL, P.

  Section 17.3.1 (page 433): PH and PSPACE.

  Section 20.2.1 (page 499): P, NP, coNP, PSPACE, EXP, NEXP, coNEXP, EXPSPACE, 2-EXP, ELEMENTARY, R.

The book also includes a nice take on time- and space-hierarchy theorems; see Chapter 7.

**EDIT:** I also recommend Complexity Zoo's [Active Inclusion Diagram](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/diagram.xml) (requires Firefox 1.5 or later, or Opera 9 or later). If you don't have that, you may try Zoo's [Static Inclusion Diagram](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/diagram.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

See the [complexity zoo](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class) and [Immermann](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/complexity_theory.html).